# returning online numeric and the + sign

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have the following string : +996a34fdsc112
I want to return only the numbers with the plus sign : +99634112
How to do it using the `replaceAll` regex function ?

Comment: [Did you try anything so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Replacing `[^\\d+]+` with an empty string should work.

Comment: Use regex `[a-z]` and replace all the matched character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
String repl = "+996a34fdsc112".replaceAll("[^+\\d]+", "");
//=> +99634112
```

Comment: what about this ? number = number.replaceAll("[^0-9+]", "");

Comment: lol :) not really sleep on this but when I am online on SO I try my best to help and answer anything that I can.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to remove all characters in range `a-z`. If that is the case then you can use

```
String noAlpha = "+996a34fdsc112".replaceAll("[a-z]+","");
```

`+` in this case represents `{1,}` which means "*at least once*", it doesn't represent `+` character from your text.